# Is there recommended Tomcat version for In Process Broker API?

Tags: web8.5, broker

When serving Web site by using Tomcat, and using Broker legacy API (in-process), is there any recommended version of Tomcat?

On RESTful API, client-side API requires only Java 8.0. This is described in following manual

[Prerequisites for client-side APIs and Web application extensions](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-4C8490C8-2476-4E0D-BF73-F0274E2ED772&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-EA943C95-AC45-40AA-A87E-3F1E39DB5373.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4C8490C8-2476-4E0D-BF73-F0274E2ED772)

Are following conditions applied for legacy API (in-process) same as client of RESTful API?

- Requires Java 8.0
- Any version of Tomcat is OK

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tomcat version:**
Looking at the [Content Delivery presentation environment Web application server support history](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3F8F4EE2-D8BF-4178-B52C-CB5B8B71A836) page in the online docs, it appears that only *Apache Tomcat 7.0* is supported for SDL Web 8.5 and, even then, it must be v7.0.47 or later.

**Java version:**
From the [Content Delivery Java and .NET support history](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-CF0EC900-6005-4C6F-A89E-BEF6394AEC44) page, only Java 8 is supported.

Comment: I asked about this issue to SDL, the answer is 'Content Delivery presentation environment Web application server support history' is available for legacy API (in-process) too.

Comment: Excellent, so it looks like Tomcat 7 (v7.0.47 and above) is the only supported version. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Tomcat 8.5.6 is also supported  on Web 8.5 according to the document.

Comment: Ah, yes, you’re correct.